# Web-map file download automation

Tags: web-mapping, browser

This [web-map](https://www.arxaiologikoktimatologio.gov.gr/), has all the archaeological sites in Greece which can be downloaded in shapefile format.

I would like to download all of them for a site suitability analysis, but the web-map does not have the option for multiple feature download.

Does anyone know if I can **automate the process** and let my computer do all the hard work for me?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what does a request look like for a single download?